# Refresh an UltraWinGrid from a separate form

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I've got a form with a list of customers and another form where customers can be added. When I open the `fAddCustomer` form, from `fCustomerList`, I'm calling it using this code:

```
Dim f As New Form
f = New fAddCustomer(con, False)
f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
f.Show()
```

On `fCustomerAdd`, I've got a `ToolStripButton` to add the customer. When the form is closed, I need to refresh the `UltraWinGrid` that I have on `fCustomerList` to view the new data on the list automatically.

Because I'm using a `ToolStripButton` and the form uses `f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent`, I can't use the same solution that was used in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396728/ultrawingrid-auto-refresh), as there is no `DialogResult` on a `ToolStripButton`, and you can't use `ShowDialog` when using `MdiParents`.

Is there any other way I can achieve this at all?

Comment: If the Add form added the data to the same datasource the `fCustomerList` used (assuming it uses a DS), you wouldnt have to refresh anything

Comment: @Plutonix The `UltraGrid` in `fCustomerList` uses a `DataSource` that is filled by performing a `SELECT` query on the database table, and the add form adds the data to the same database table (Directly to the DB, not via a `DataSource`)

Comment: Yes, and because the second form adds directly to the DB, your first form has to requery to show any new data.  None of that is needed if new data is added to the same DataSource

Comment: So, pass in the `DataSource` and add the data to that? Then "upsert" the datasource at a later stage?

Comment: With a fully configured DataAdapter, you can store many many changes and apply them all at once.  It doesnt matter what actor adds/deletes/changes things.  They can also do an actual refresh - load just the new rows added such as by others running the same app - with one method

Comment: _Is there any other way I can achieve this at all?_ Sure, wire up the [FormClosed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) event...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Ah, but that won't allow me to reload the data on another form.

Comment: Sure it will.  The FormClosed() event would fire in the Form that you want to Refresh().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One that you could achieve this without changing the `DataSource` passing as @Plutonix suggested is to do something like this:

```
Private Sub fAddCustomer_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

Try
    If Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of fCustomerList).Any Then
       Application.OpenForms("fCustomerList").Close()
            Dim f As New fCustomerList()
            f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
            f.Show()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example:

```
' ... in fCustomerList ...
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New fAddCustomer(con, False)
    f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
    AddHandler f.FormClosed, AddressOf f_FormClosed
    f.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub f_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    ' ... refresh your UltraWinGrid ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Ooooh, this is really interesting, wasn't aware of this being possible! I'd already done it the way that was suggested in the previous answer so I've accepted that, but in future I'll definitely give this a go!